# Will updating Magento mean starting again with theme customisation?

Tags: template, theme, magento2, migration

For the last week I have been editing a theme ready to launch my first e-commerce website. At first, Magento seemed to confuse the idea of creating a website, but as I'm learning I can see / understand it's benefits. I now feel somewhat comfortable (proud?) that i've got my site roughly where I want it to be.

Enter Magento 2.0...

Will updating Magento cause any issues or alteration with the work I have already done?

and

Is NOT updating a bad idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing you've built for Magento 1 will be directly compatible with Magento 2. You can keep your data with the data migration tool, but everything else--theme, extensions, customizations--must be rebuilt. New platform.

That being said, Magento 2 is still in beta. The final General Availability release won't be for at least another month, and even then it will take time before everything is up to speed and running smoothly. Some extensions will be available, but not anywhere near the breadth of what is out there for Magento 1 right now.

So for right now, October 2015, no, I would not worry about Magento 2. Release what you're proud of. Magento 1 won't be going anywhere, and it's a fairly stable platform. A year or two down the line, you can reevaluate.

Comment: Good answer, I'll be sticking/building with Magento 1.9.X for a while yet (~1 year)